# Final Cut Pro X: iMac or Mac Pro for House of Worship?

Tags: video, osx, video-editing

I need to purchase a new Mac to run Final Cut Pro X.

- We plan to use FCPX to edit video of our weekly church service shot by 3 cameras.
- Sound will come directly from the sound board.
- I don't expect we'll use much in the way of filters/effects, etc. (This is new territory for me so I don't know for sure if that's accurate.)
- The final videos will be high definition.
- The video will be posted online and in the future we intend to stream the video live to a remote campus and are considering the possibility of using a QuickTime server.

Based on my research, I understand the importance of hardware components for this workflow to be in this order:

1. Video card/Amount of VRAM
2. Storage speed
3. Processor speed
4. Amount of system memory

It seems obvious the "best" setup would be a Mac Pro (currently $2999+ without a display).  But with a not-for-profit budget, if I don't have to spend $4000 for a complete setup I'd rather not.

Assume an an iMac with these specs:

- 3.2GHz quad-core Intel Core i5 processor (Turbo Boost up to 3.6GHz)
- 8GB (two 4GB) memory, configurable up to 32GB
- 1TB Fusion Drive
- AMD Radeon R9 M390 with 2GB video memory

Would FCPX used as I describe above on these specs of an iMac make for a lot of waiting on the system while editing?  Should I be looking at something different in hardware?

Comment: I'm not entirely qualified to answer the question as I haven't owned either (thus a comment instead of a proper answer), but I've done much of what you're considering (except live streaming) on a 2012 non-Retina Macbook Pro. I suspect either machine would be overkill, but I'll let someone qualified answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAM is probably the main change I would make to your proposed specs.

#### Narrowing Down the Options

If you're going to want an iMac, especially for video editing, you're going to need a fast hard-disk, enough RAM, and definitely a good GPU. This immediately narrows down the selection to a 27-in 5K iMac. Why? The 5K iMacs are the only ones offering discrete graphics. The 21" iMac offers only a 5400RPM hard disk which is *much* too slow for video-editing.

#### The Optimal Specs

I'm going to assume you're editing 1080p video. 1080p video directly out of a camera can is around 300MP, for 10 minutes. OS X tend to use around ~4GB for the system, running Final Cut, live streaming video, and handling audio, 8GB might run out quickly. At the least 16GB what I'd say is the *minimum* RAM for your case. 32GB would be best.

#### What I'd Recommend

I'm going to recommend the 27" 5K iMac with:

- 3.2GHz quad-core i5 (base CPU)
- 16GB RAM
- 1TB Fusion Drive
- AMD Radeon R9 M380 with 2GB video memory (base GPU)

With 16GB of RAM, this comes out to $1,969.00, and with 32GB $2,329.00

#### Alternative RAM Option

If you're comfortable with manually upgrading the RAM (yes, 27" 5K iMac has user-upgradable RAM). You can purchase an 8GB model and use a [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/1600DDR3S32S/) RAM upgrade kit (only $129-$249).

This brings your total price for a 16GB to $1,918 and for 32GB to $2,038

Comment: Excellent detailed answer.  I'm purchasing a 27" iMac with specs similar to those you've proposed, including the 1 TB Fusion drive.  I also purchased an external USB 3.0 SATA dock and a 2.5" SSD to copy the video to and edit from in order to get good disk I/O without having to pay so much for an SSD system disk.